# How do I extract multiple lines of code using Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl, matching, multiline

I am trying to extract all of the IP Addresses off of this website: http://www.game-monitor.com/

I want to regex the IP's on that page, extract all of them and display them on the screen.

This is what I have so far, can you tell me what Is wrong and help me?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use HTTP::Request;
use LWP::UserAgent;

print 'Press [1] To Begin: ';
chomp ($begin = <STDIN>);

my $url = 'http://www.game-monitor.com/';
my @ips = ('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}','\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}','\d{1,2}   \.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,3}','\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,3}','\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}','\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}','\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}','\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}','\d{1,2}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}','\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,3}');

if ($begin eq 1)
{
my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
my $useragent = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response = $useragent->request($request);
my $result = $response->content;

foreach $ip (@ips)
{
if ($result =~ /($ips[0])/ ||
$result =~ /($ips[1])/ ||
$result =~ /($ips[2])/ ||
$result =~ /($ips[3])/ ||
$result =~ /($ips[4])/ ||
$result =~ /($ips[5])/ ||
$result =~ /($ips[6])/ ||
$result =~ /($ips[7])/ ||
$result =~ /($ips[8])/ ||
$result =~ /($ips[9])/
)
{
    print "IP: $1 \n";
    print "IP: $2 \n";
    print "IP: $3 \n";
    print "IP: $4 \n";
    print "IP: $5 \n";
    print "IP: $6 \n";
    print "IP: $7 \n";
    print "IP: $8 \n";
    print "IP: $9 \n";
    print "IP: $10 \n";
}
}
}
```

Comment: what problem are you having?  what error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use HTTP::Request;
use LWP::UserAgent;


my $url = 'http://www.game-monitor.com/';
my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
my $useragent = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response = $useragent->request($request);
my $result = $response->content;

@m = ($result =~ /\b(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\b/sg);
foreach (@m) {
        print "IP: $_\n";
}
```

Comment: I executed this code, but no result? Does it take a while to extract the Ip's?

Comment: It works perfectly for me. May be the remote website is slow.

Answer (score 3):

To simplify multi-line substitutions, use the `/s modifier`, which in effect tells Perl to pretend the string is a single line--even if it isn't.

see [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) for more detail.

It would be nice if you use module like [Regexp::Common::net](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common-2011041701/lib/Regexp/Common/net.pm) -- provide regexes for IPv4 addresses instead of writing your own regex for matching ip addresses.

for example try something like,

```
use Regexp::Common qw/net/;
while (<>) {
  print $1, "\n" if /($RE{net}{ipv4})/;
}
```

Comment: I don't see what the `s` modifier is good for in this case. `g` is needed here to match all occurrences.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `/g` modifier to match all IPs.
Tip: use `-w` parameter and `strict` package to avoid "bad coding style".

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use HTTP::Request;
use LWP::UserAgent;

print 'Press [1] To Begin: ';
chomp (my $begin = <STDIN>);

my $url = 'http://www.game-monitor.com/';
my $ip_regex = '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}';

if ($begin eq 1)
{
    my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
    my $useragent = LWP::UserAgent->new();
    my $response = $useragent->request($request);
    my $result = $response->content;

    while ($result =~ /($ip_regex)/g)
    {
        print "IP: $1 \n";
    }

}
```

Comment: I executed this code, but no result? Does it take a while to extract the Ip's?

Comment: For me it worked ... I get approx. 100 IP addresses in return. Do you have any error messages?

Comment: Hm, that's odd. I don't get any error messages, just a ticker flashing constantly not displaying anything.

Comment: How do you run your code? I do it on Linux shell `perl ip.pl`

Comment: Try with removed `if ($begin eq 1)` line.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see what you're trying to do with your big array `@ips`. The first regex already matches all IP addresses (since `\d{1,3}` means "one to three digits", it already contains IP addresses that have two digits), so you don't need all those permutations with `\d{1,2}`.

One thing you could do is to surround your regex with `\b` word boundary anchors to ensure that you don't match `123.123.123.123` within `99123.123.123.12399` or something like it. Also, you're probably aware that your regex would also match something like `999.999.999.999`. If that's not a problem because your input won't contain invalid IP addresses, then of course that's just fine.

Finally, you need the `/g` global modifier so your regex finds not just the first but all occurrences in the string.

In essence, how about doing it like this:

```
while ($result =~ m/\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/g) {
    print "IP: $&\n";
}
```

Comment: I executed this code, but no result? Does it take a while to extract the Ip's?

Comment: Can you post (an excerpt of) `$result` in your question so we can see what it contains?

Comment: When I said 'no result' I meant nothing shows up on the screen, just a ticker flashing; nothing is wrong with $result lol.

Comment: I understand, but I'd like to see what's in `$result` so I can reproduce why my regex wouldn't match.